# case on where statement with date

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am trying to filter data on a date based on month. I went through different solutions in here but couldn't get it to work. I am trying to filter if month is less than march to use 2020 else get 2021 data.

I have tried 2 solutions based on different feed back:

```
select * 
from db.table1
where 
(case
(to_char(commit_date, 'mm')<'03') then 
(to_char(commit_date, 'mm')= (to_char(sysdate, 'mm')-1)
and to_char(commit_date, 'yyyy') = '2020') 
else 
(to_char(commit_date, 'mm')= (to_char(sysdate, 'mm')-1)
and to_char(commit_date, 'yyyy') = '2021') 
end)
```

This gives mme invalid relational operator.

Another solution

```
select * 
from db.table1

where 
(
(to_char(commit_date, 'mm')<'03' and to_char(commit_date, 'yyyy') = '2020') or (to_char(commit_date, 'yyyy') = '2021'))
```

doesn't seem to filter.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: The second one looks like it should work, though you could simplify it with `extract()` and/or using date ranges, as D-Shih showed. Is what you've shown the complete query, or do you follow that with more conditions, with `or`?

Comment: Although you also said "if month is less than march" - but which month? Based on the case version, is that maybe supposed to be if the *current* month is before (and not including) March? And are you only looking for a single month's worth of data - perhaps the month before today's date, but either 1 or 2 years ago? Please edit your question to fully explain you logic, and give examples.

Comment: What I am trying to get is month worth of current year and month based on the condition. For jan and feb, if today's month is Jan I want to extract Jan 2020 and Jan 2022, if todays month is March, I want to extract Mar2021 and March 2022 data. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `TO_DATE` function greater and equal than `2020-01-01` and smaller than `2020-03-01` or `EXTRACT` year equal 2021

```
SELECT * 
FROM db.table1
WHERE
  (commit_date >= TO_DATE('2020-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND commit_date < TO_DATE('2020-03-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
OR
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM commit_date) = 2021
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. I didn't know about extract function :)